# Cannot close workbook after running macro with userform and listbox

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the code below to make navigation through workbook easier.  However, after running the macro cursor movement is odd (restricted range and jumping).  In addition the workbook does not close when clicking on the red "x" to close the window.  Further, the group and ungroup icons (for hiding or expanding rows and columns) does not work.  It appears that somehow "control" is still in VBA as supposed to normal Excel.  All help seriously appreciated.

**Userform code:**

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim ShList()
    Dim ShCount As Integer
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim ListPos As Integer

    ShCount = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    ReDim Preserve ShList(1 To ShCount)

    For x = 1 To ShCount
        If Sheets(x).Name = ActiveSheet.Name Then
            ListPos = x - 1
        End If
        ShList(x) = Sheets(x).Name
    Next x

    With ListBox1
        .List = ShList
        .ListIndex = ListPos
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Sheets(ListBox1.Value).Activate
    Unload UserForm1
End Sub
```

**Click button to activate code:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub WorksheetSelect_Click()
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't have a problem with this.  Does doing a "Control-Break" do anything?  How about looking at the Task Manager/Performance graph? (Ctl-Alt-Del)

Comment: "Ctrl-Break" does not have any impact, and there is nothing significant in Task Manager, performance is stable.

Comment: I am using Excel 2013, Windows 64-bit . . .

Comment: I tested this in a brand new workbook, same result.  I even ran a Microsoft Office repair, issue persists.  It seems to start after I've run the macro a couple of times.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and had to remove the following code:
Sheets(1).Activate

After removing it, I was able to close the Excel as always.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It was solved by changing any cell value in any cell on the active worksheet as last row in my VBA code. In my case I added the VBA code: Range("A1") = "_", but you could also change any other cell to any other value.

Answer (score -1):

sorry not using comment, because its too long, just analyzing your code

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1 'someone tell me what's this ? i might be noob at this point

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim ShList() 'as variant
Dim ShCount As Integer 'as Long
Dim x As Integer 'as long
Dim ListPos As Integer 'as Long

ShCount = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count 
ReDim Preserve ShList(1 To ShCount) 'remove preserve

For x = 1 To ShCount
    If Sheets(x).Name = ActiveSheet.Name Then
        ListPos = x - 1
    End If
    ShList(x) = Sheets(x).Name
Next x

With ListBox1 'i usually write : with Me.Listbox1, but i guess its ok
    .List = ShList
    .ListIndex = ListPos
End With

'add erase ShList (free memory)
End Sub
```

so main thing, remove Preserve, and add a Erase for your Array

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to review the above.  I incorporated all your suggestions but the problem persists.  I subsequently discovered that if I select another tab (not the active worksheet) and then the intended worksheet, the problem goes away.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to review the code above.  I incorporated all your suggestions but the problem persists.  I subsequently discovered that if (after the macro run is complete) I manually select another worksheet (not the active worksheet) and then the intended worksheet, the problem goes away. I then added code to simulate selecting a different sheet and then the intended sheet, but then the problem does not go away.

Comment: the problem may be in the content of your activesheet. try to reset the usedrange with : `dim a as long       a=activesheet.usedrange.rows.count` .   if not working make a loop to every sheet in workbook: `For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets` and replace `=activesheet.` by `= Sh.`

Comment: i remember having issues with a workbook once, when using text speech functions in excell, had to remove it because it made every VBA code unstable. (application.speech, or range().speak , something like that): dont use! also if you have tricky formulas or whatever (named ranges...), apply application.enableevents=false and same to .calculation=xlmanual at the begin of code, and reset to normal at the end